# react - useState for changing opacity with transition effect works quirky?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some problems with my code atm..

1. as the lightbox function gets called the opacity goes from 1 to 0, and then to 1 / where as i would like it to go only from 0 to 1. This problem also happens when i set the Opacity to 0 directly in the main div's class.
2. on the websites first load, the first time i trigger the lightbox it goes only from 1 - 0 opacity / and i then have to click (making it render an empty `div` class), and then "reactivate" the lightbox, where it then works as stated above.
3. I don't know how to make it go smoothly back to 0, as doing the following doesn't work.

---

```
else {
        setOpacity(0);
        setTimeout(function () {
            return(
                <div></div>
            )
          }, 1000);
    }
```

---

This is how the code looks now:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function Lightbox(props){
    const [opacity, setOpacity] = useState(0)

    const handleClick = () => {
        setOpacity(0);
        props.click()
        setTimeout(function () {
            setOpacity(1);
          }, 1000);
    }

    if(props.lightbox){
        return(
            <div style={{opacity}} className={"lightbox-container"} id="lightbox" onClick={handleClick}>
                <img src={props.pitem.src} alt={props.pitem.title}></img>
                <div className="lightbox-text">
                    <div className="lightbox-h1">
                        <h1>{props.pitem.title}</h1>
                        <h2>{'(' + props.pitem.type + ')'}</h2>
                    </div>
                    <h2>{props.pitem.director ? "Director: " + props.pitem.director : null || props.pitem.production ? "Production: " + props.pitem.production : null}</h2>
                    <h2>{"role: " + props.pitem.role}</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    } else {
        return(
            <div></div>
        )
    }
}

export default Lightbox\
```

---

```
.lightbox-container{
    z-index: 999;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
    backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
    background:linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(0, 0, 0), rgba(30, 47, 92, 0.9));
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Comment: What this props.click() do?

Comment: It sets a boolean to false inside the main class component which in turn makes this component return the empty div.